# The database cluster initialization failed - error while installing PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

While installing PostgreSQL on Windows 11 I get the error:

> the database cluster initialization failed

then SQL Shell gives me an error

> psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> (0x0000274D/10061)
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432? Press any key to continue . . .

There's even no Postgres in Services and the data folder is empty. So I uninstalled it and got this error while doing so:

> error stopping service PostgreSQL-x64-13

After this, I've tried many different ways of reinstalling Postgres, including running it as Admin, creating a separate user named postgres with Admin rights, etc. In fact, this comprehensive article offers a lot of different ways to deal with this issue: https://forums.holdemmanager.com/general-support/150771-solved-postgresql-database-cluster-initialisation-failed.html

However, none of them worked for me. It seems that I exhausted all possible solutions. Any ideas on what I can try now?

Comment: Anything in the installation log file?

Comment: @Laurenz the log file pg_log is supposed to be in the data directory? but my data directory is completely empty, no conf files or logs

Comment: There are some files written by the installer. Look for those.

Comment: @Laurenz you mean the file installation_summary? I see it but there's no error:


Installation Directory: D:\programs\psql
Server Installation Directory: D:\programs\psql
...
Stack Builder Installation Directory: D:\programs\psql\stackbuilder
Installation Log: C:\Users\postgres.DESKTOP-V156SKM\AppData\Local\Temp\install-postgresql.log
===== Installation completed at: 2022-02-21(YYYY-MM-DD) - 13:25:04(HH:MM:SS) =====